# How do I make sense of this diagram from Google's deep learning course?

Tags: python, deep-learning, logistic-regression

I have been enjoying Google's deep learning course while finding it relatively difficult. I am still in the first section which is going through multinomial logistic classification, specifically in regards to classifying pictures of letters according to what letter they contain.

While I kind of get it, I am struggling to understand this diagram quite a bit.

https://postimg.org/image/lk4369cl5/

[image]

I suppose what confuses me the most is how the input X, which I assumes is a big matrix of pixel values, becomes converted into a matrix with 1 column and 3 rows, with the title y in the diagram. I don't get how applying the formula wx + b to the input matrix X would give a 3x1 matrix y in the diagram. It really seems in this diagram that regardless of the size of X you get a output matrix y that has 1 row for each possible classification (in this case A, B or C) but that doesn't make sense given the model is wx + b, the size of y should be the same as the size of X - but then that doesn't make sense because then you have this giant matrix of y values which i don't know how you classify.

Furthermore I don't really understand what y is? Does y just have one number for each of the possible classifications x can be, with a higher number suggesting it is that classification?

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud730/lessons/6370362152/concepts/63798118260923#

I think I get how softmax is calculated from y.

Thanks

Comment: in question you should add link to this tutorial. BTW. it probably only example - if you use bigger matrix X then you get bigger Y , etc.

Comment: sadly, i need more reputation to include 2 links. I dont get if the X matrix is 5 million x 5 million in size does that mean the y matrix will be that size too and if so what does that mean for interpreting the y matrix and converting it to softmax.

Comment: @slimshady add link on comment

Comment: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud730/lessons/6370362152/concepts/63798118260923# my question is from the first section of the course @Spiderman

Comment: here W and b are matrices too.